# Infinite While Loop Not Working C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am coding in C++, and thought that I would create a game for my sister. However, when I run my code, it only runs once, even though I have a while loop that should make it run infinite times. I am using Code Blocks and the GCC GNU Compiler. When I run the code, it ends after the if statement and doesn't run the cout after either...
Here is the code (it is for my sister, so it may be dumb):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Welcome to Uni Game" << endl;
    cout << "the fun unicorn game!" << endl;
    string riding;
    int happiness = 0;
    while (0 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Would you like to a: ride a unicorn b: feed your unicorn c: lead your unicorn? ";
        cin >> riding;
        if (riding == "a")
            cout << "You jump onto your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You ride your unicorn through the park, seeing loads of flowers!" << endl;
            cout << "After your horse eats loads of flowers, you head back to the stable." << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 3;
            break;
        if (riding == "b")
            cout <<  "You feed your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You give it its favorite wheat, which it absolutely loves!" << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 2;
            break;
        if (riding == "c")
            cout << "You grab a lead for your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You head to the paddock and lead your unicorn for a walk." << endl;
            cout << "Your unicorn loves this!" << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 1;
            break;
        cout << "Your happiness level is: " << happiness;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the `break` statement does?

Comment: You're missing braces around the body of your `if` statements.

Comment: it ends the if right

Comment: Why do you blame your sister?

Comment: where do I put the braces?

Comment: Can you point out which chapter in your C++ book claims that `break` "ends the if" statement? If you actually have a C++ book that says that, you need a new C++ book. Because it doesn't. It ends the nearest enclosing `while` or `for` statement. So your program is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: but now the program runs all the if statements

Comment: is there some other statement that ends the if?

Comment: oh ok got it, thanks so much guys

Comment: You need better learning resources. Really. I think you are a victim of an incompetent tutorial site.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, a multi-line conditional block can be written in the following way.

```
if (condition) {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

This calls the functions `foo` and `bar` if and only if `condition` is `true` or returns `true` when converted to a `bool`.

If the braces are omitted, only one command is governed by the conditional.

```
if (condition)
    foo();
bar();
```

Here `foo` is only executed if `condition` is `true`, but `bar` is executed regardless of the value of `condition`.  So one way of writing a set of mutually exclusive blocks is to do something like this.

```
if (riding == "a") {
    std::cout << "Fun text." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "More text." << std::endl;
}
if (riding == "b") {
// etc.
```

Notice the lack of `break`.  `break` does something unrelated.  It ends the loop that it's called in.  That's why your loop stops.

You could make the above code more efficient by sprinkling in some `else` keywords to prevent checking conditions you know to be mutually exclusive.

```
if (riding == "a") {
    // Somethin'.
} else if (riding == "b") {
    // Somethin' else.
} else if (riding == "c") {
    // Somethin' much more else.
} else {
    std::cerr << "Unrecognized option '" << riding << "'." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

If each of your options is going to be only a single letter in length, you could also make `riding` a `char` and take advantage of the `switch` syntax.

```
switch (riding) {
    case 'a':
        // Something.
        break;
    case 'b':
        // Something.
        break;
    case 'c':
        // Something.
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << riding << "?  Hey, buddy, no one tells me to " << riding << "." << std::endl;
        return 1;
}
```

And now you get your `break` keywords back.  `break` is also used to end a `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Put brackets around each if statement to end the if statement, and take out the break statements because they end the while loop, not the if statement.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not need a break statement to terminate an if statement.

The if statement will automatically terminate once the last line of code within it is executed.

in your case, using the 'break' statement terminates the while loop, not the if statement, which results in your program only running once.

Secondly, Try removing the break statements and add a set of '{}' to each of the if statement.

you can also add 'else' statements to the if statements after the first if statement, this makes the program more efficient. For example if the first if statement is true, then there is no need to check the other if statements as they will not need to be executed

For example...

```
    if(riding == a)
    {
        //Execute some code...
    }

    else if(riding == b)
    {
        //Execute some code...
    }

    else if(riding == c)
    {
        //Execute some code...
    }
```

Also, instead of using a comparison in your while loop, try using the 'true' statement.

```
    #include <instream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Welcome to Uni Game" << endl;
    cout << "the fun unicorn game!" << endl;
    string riding;
    int happiness = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Would you like to a: ride a unicorn b: feed your unicorn c: lead your unicorn? ";
        cin >> riding;

        if (riding == "a")
        {
            cout << "You jump onto your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You ride your unicorn through the park, seeing loads of flowers!" << endl;
            cout << "After your horse eats loads of flowers, you head back to the stable." << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 3;
        }

       else if (riding == "b")
       {
            cout <<  "You feed your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You give it its favorite wheat, which it absolutely loves!" << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 2;
       }

       else if (riding == "c")
       {
            cout << "You grab a lead for your unicorn!" << endl;
            cout << "You head to the paddock and lead your unicorn for a walk." << endl;
            cout << "Your unicorn loves this!" << endl;
            happiness = happiness + 1;

        cout << "Your happiness level is: " << happiness;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the `break` and you're good to go. The `if` statements are well indented and no problem with that.